# Is there a useful pattern for unit testing with gmock for grpc Server classes?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, grpc, googletest, googlemock

It's tremendously helpful that there's a tool to generate mock versions of the client stubs. Testing the server side is causing me tons of headache at the moment. Enough headache where I feel like I must be doing something fundamentally wrong.

I may be misreading the following, but the end2end tests, including 'mock_test' seem to be using an actual client-server connection to drive testing. They may mock out the client, or mock out the client readers/writers to see the response from the server, but it's not clear to me how to test the server in isolation.

What I want to be able to do: I have some Service implentation that inherits from the gRPC generated class "Service." suppose that service exposes an interface `::grpc::Status Foo(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const CommandMessage* request, ::grpc::ServerWriter<CommandResponse>* writer);` My gut for writing unit tests is saying to pass in a mock "ServerWriter" class and expect 'Write' is called when appropriate. But ServerWriter is marked final and can't be overridden.

This isn't the first place I've run into trouble with my kind of standard ways of mocking and gRPC's server stuff. The Server class, the ServerBuilder class, etc. I've wrapped so that I could put mock versions of them into tests (to validate that the correct parameters are being passed to my Server when it's being constructed, e.g.)

So I think I'm missing something with grpc then. I just don't know what. Am I supposed to stand up a real server in my unit tests and probe it with a mock client? How do I validate the proper server configurations are being passed, if I have to stand up a test version with test configurations? The code has interface classes and virtual methods, but then the parts that seem exposed for public use don't seem to be easily mockable as I'd expect.